# Is there historical evidence for Christ's resurrection?

Tags: religion, jesus-christ

[Numerous Christian sources claim that the raising from dead by Jesus Christ is “historically proven”](https://www.google.com/search?q=jesus%20resurrection%20historical%20evidence). A claim that is formed this way clearly goes beyond the scope of faith alone. Therefore I believe it may be appropriate to ask on this side:

How convincing is the historical evidence for Christ raising from the dead?

Comment: Might be interesting: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/43112/what-evidence-is-there-for-the-resurrection-of-jesus

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based. Looking at the first couple of google results you linked, "evidence" that is presented are things like "an empty tomb existed somewhere", "Jesus' disciples say so", "the bible says so", "Women say so", "Why else would Christianity exist?", "Some people believed it back then", "Why would anyone lie about this?". Whether or not you think that these are evidence for a supernatural event is faith-based and can't be answered here. On the other hand, asking if some of these are true - eg if there is historical evidence for Jesus' empty grave - would be on-topic.

Comment: "Numerous Christian sources..." Not relatively speaking. In almost 2000 years of christian apologetics and magisterial teachings, practically no christians have claimed that the resurrection is "historically proven", (speaking  in the modern sense: "evidence" that can be judged objectively, apart from faith). The typical claim is that history can (at most) prove that "the first christian community strongly believed that Jesus was raised from the dead". One cannot leap from that pressumed fact to the affirmation "I believe Jesus was raised from the dead" - not with history -  not without faith.

Comment: Please identify and quote one notable claim rather than summarizing many claims.

Comment: There is not even any indisputable evidence that Jesus of Nazareth actually existed.  The Christian Gospels all date from well after his supposed death.  AFAIK, the only other mentions are in Josephus, and may be authentic or later additions.

Comment: The linked question already contains a good summary of historical evidence of Jesus (proof of resurrection => proof of existence)

Comment: I don't object to the closing of this question, but this is NOT a duplicate of "Did Jesus live?", they are very different questions.

Comment: @leonbloy as stated in the closing banner: "This question already has an answer (t)here". Duplication is about the answers not the questions.

Comment: @Sklivvz Uh I'm not sure how can this be the case, since duplication means no new answers can even be added to the closed question, while they should not be added to the "duplicate" question since it asks a different question. Having said that, I'm not opposed to the closing of this question either.